# Writing to registry problem on different Windows versions

Tags: winapi, registry

**Problem**: I need to create registry keys in my simple application (MS VC++ project), but this simple application could work in different modes:

- if I launch it with WinXP, it's started as a *service*
- if I launch it with Vista or Win7, it's started as a console window

On WinXP, I could install service and also I could write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\` section. It's ok.

*But*, when I'm trying to launch my application on Vista/Win7, and it trying **to save some data** to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\` registry section, I get the error message, that I can't do that.

**Question**: Could anyone tell me, where I could write (create) some data (keys) in registry on all of this systems WinXP, Vista, Seven.

---

PS. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` section I'm unable to use, because, services are working on it's own sessions, so data stored by user in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` will not be accessible to service.

PSS. I'm unable to give the administrator rights to the application for save some data. I need another "folder" in registry to write there "for free".

---

Code examples:

```
REGKEY service(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services"), KEY_READ, REGKEY::open);
REGKEY app(service, TEXT("my_application"), REGKEY::create);
// here comes error
```

Comment: Perhaps on Windows XP you can use HKLM and on Windows 7 you could use HKCU?

Comment: That's the whole purpose, you can't write to HKLM if you don't have sufficient rights.

Comment: @Grim Currently my code organized as you describe: for XP HKLM, and for Vista/Win7 I used HKCU, but I think that this is not the right choice... I think, that I will try to use INI files for that purpose!

Comment: If thats the case you should use whatever Alex K. suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UAC prevents access to HKLM on Visa/7/2008, so without elevation to administrative privileges your application cannot access keys contained within it.

If you can't use HKCU then your best bet is to store the data on disk in a format of your choice, in a directory under `CommonApplicationData` created by your installer with the appropriate permissions.